# Xamarin form: Can we switch resources at runtime

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, resourcedictionary

I have a different text for a set of buttons and wanted to put the text into resource dictionary. Is there a way to group the resources and switch to different resource at runtime when the button clicked.

Let say I have button A and B each have 3 different text resources. When I clicked a next button for example, the text on button A and B will switched to use second set of text in the set of resource dictionary.

Comment: You can try DynamicResource

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `{DynamicResource}` instead of `{StaticResource}`, the content of your label will be updated when the Resource is updated.